# Scraping table from web link

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table, rvest

I want to extract the Holdings table from [Here](https://whalewisdom.com/stock/spy) 
I have the following code:

```
 library(rvest)

 turl = 'https://whalewisdom.com/stock/spy'
 test_html = read_html(turl) 
 df<-html_table(test_html)
```

However on running it i get the following error:

> Error in matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) :    invalid
>   'ncol' value (too large or NA) In addition: Warning messages: 1: In
>   max(p) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf 2: In
>   matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) :   NAs introduced by
>   coercion to integer range

Comment: I am not sure if this is the entire problem, but that table seems to be filled asynchronously by an AJAX call after the page loads.  I do not see the data for the table in "View Source" in the browser, nor in the data returned by read_html.  I am not sure there is an R solution for scraping asynchronously loaded web pages, but perhaps someone else knows of one.  A non-R solution may be [headless browsers](http://toddhayton.com/2015/03/20/scraping-with-casperjs/)

Comment: Thanks. This was my concern too. I could not find a link to the table page embedded in the source code so was wondering where the data is being called from.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I came across the same situation, through searching around I came across a solution to this at [R Studio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-skip-empty-table-while-scraping-with-rvest-html-table/27597)

I hope this will be helpful to you too.

Comment: It is preferable to post solution direct on SO. A bare link is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Index for the table of interest or simply grab the appropriate table node and use fill=True then do a little tidying on contents

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

t <- (read_html('https://whalewisdom.com/stock/spy') %>%
          html_node('form + .table') %>%
          html_table(fill=T))
```